# Why can't I access my object property after loading it into a variable of the class type

Tags: grails, groovy, nullpointerexception, gsp

This is probably the most trivial question but I can not get my head around why I'm getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException`here?

`basecurr` retrieves the right object with `symbol` and `name` already populated but I can't access them:

**GSP page**

```
<g:form name="selectCurrencyForm" url="[action:'getrates',controller:'currency']">
    <g:select name="currency_one" from="${Currency?.list()}" optionValue="name" optionKey="id"/>
    <g:submitButton name="submit" value="Show Rates" />
</g:form>
```

**Method in Controller:**

```
def getrates(){
    Currency basecurr = Currency.get(params.currency_one)
    println basecurr.symbol
}
```

**Class Currency**

```
class Currency {
    String symbol
    String name
    String rate

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

The above throws `java.lang.NullPointerException` when accessing the `symbol` property of `basecurr` for `println`

**Adding the exception stack**

```
    2014-07-25 00:35:47,214 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  -           NullPointerException occurred when processing request: [GET] /Appname/Controller/getrates
Stacktrace follows:
Message: null
    Line | Method
->>   26 | getrates  in exchangeratechecker.ExchangeRateController$$EOkyECes
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    198 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: I can't see anywhere in your code where you're accessing the `symbol` property. Could you show the stacktrace and the code that's causing the exception to be thrown

Comment: I edited `println basecurr.symbol`, calling `symbol` causes the null pointer exception. `println basecurr` works as it should

Comment: I don't see any error with your code. When you `println basecurr`, do you see the expected value of symbol in there? Make sure symbol cannot be NULL in the database.

Comment: I'm going crazy over this! symbol is not null because I can see it in the database. When I print basecurr it prints: `currencychecker.Currency : 1` which seemingly is the right object pulled from the DB. Nevertheless I still get the silly NullPointer exception with no message as soon as I append anything to basecurr :(

Comment: @Dinoo I just tested something. If I create a NEW Currency called temp and assign basecurr to it and then try to println temp.symbol then it works! Does this have anything to do with instantiation? My case here is that I just want to recall an object from DB not to actually create a new one.

Comment: This isn't causing your problem but FYI... there is no good reason to use the null safe operator in the expression `Currency?.list()`.  `Currency` is a class reference and it isn't possible for that to be null.  You can just do `Currency.list()`.

Comment: Try using `Currency.read(params.currency_one)` or `Currency.findById(params.currency_one)` instead of `Currency.get(params.currency_one)`

Comment: Tried all three with no avail. All the same! It's really strange! It's like I have the object but I can't access its properties. Might it be because I have messed with some SQL database script by mistake while fiddling with DB migrate plugin  and now get, read and findBy can't fetch objects correctly? I get a "DB not found warning when I run the app" eventhough I have the tables and I can query them. I'm really tired of this! it's wasted my whole day...Any troubleshooting ideas are appreciated

Comment: I'm not pretty sure what the problem is... But, can you try to use the fully qualified classname? My guess is that since Grails uses java.util.* import always, it gets "confused", because of [java.util.Currency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html)

Comment: fully qualified name for Currency also didn't help. So frustrating

Comment: added the exception stack

Answer (score 0):

I would try writing an Integration test to eliminate the GSP code.  Can you get a Currency Object by ID and print that?  What kind of DB are you using?

```
void "Getting Currency"() {
    given:
    def currency= Currency.findById(1L)
    println("Currency: "+currency)
    println("Currency Symbol: "+currency.symbol)
    expect:
    currency != null
}
```

Comment: I'm using `"jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"` for db connection using hibernate. I don't really know anything about hibernate, this the default setting.

Comment: GSP code is correct ! if I `println parems.currency_one` I get what I expect

Answer (score 0):

The exception is occurring on the second line of this action

```
def getrates(){
    Currency basecurr = Currency.get(params.currency_one)
    println basecurr.symbol
}
```

So it seems that the only possible explanation is that there is no `Currency` with an ID that matches `params.currency_one`, so this returns null

```
Currency basecurr = Currency.get(params.currency_one)
```

Comment: `println params.currency_one` returns the right thing e.g "SYM". `println basecurr` returns `exchangeratechecker.Currency : 1`
That makes me thank that the object is actually correctly found and is in basecurr

Answer (score 0):

Your domain class and controller should have the same package and your view should include an import page directive for the `Currency` class, otherwise, Groovy will use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html because Groovy imports `java.util.*` automatically for you.

The NPE is caused by the fact that the first time you try to access `/currency/getrates` there will be no `currency_one` in the `params` map, so `basecurr` will naturally be null. Use the save navigation operator - `basecurr?.symbol` to avoid the exception.

If you manage to render the view for the first time, then there shouldn't be any problems in subsequent calls.